# If a State government breaks down, does the Federal government step in or declare it a deadzone?

Tags: internal-consistency, politics, government, alternate-reality

The world I am creating revolves around having an entire State not function at its governmental level - meaning no State police force, no continuity for municipal amenities (no running water, maintained roads, internet or telephone lines).

Essentially, pandemonium has broken out and most of the citizens have left to neighbouring states. Prisons have been unlocked, and every facet of society has devolved into a fight for scarce resources and survival.

However, outside state lines, life is relatively normal. There are no news crews reporting from inside the state, so nobody gets further information except from any new arrivals.

Crime amongst the remaining population is rampant - essentially, anarchy rules. Is it correct that in the modern US - which is the basis for my world, most of the day-to-day running of the state is down to the State government and not the Federal government?

Ultimately, if a State government breaks down, does the Federal government:

- Step in and send in the army to sort things out?
- Declares the state a deadzone and declines to further comment?

Comment: History is made of many chains of interrelated events, and the journey is as important than the destination: as physicists would say, it's nonholonomic. The answer to this question depends very much on *how* that American state get into the described situation. In normal times, this simply cannot happen. Most American states are very large and diverse, and those who are small are very unlikely to ever break down. You cannot simply say that one of the several united American states broke down -- you must describe the path which brought it there, or else readers will find the story unbelievable.

Comment: In support of @AlexP's comment, The Fed's response to a state that does break down is also about the journey, not the destination.  I regret that I must vote to close this question as too story-based because the response of the Feds isn't a condition of a rule of your world, it's literally the story you're trying to tell.  (BTW, please don't take the close vote personally, it's purpose is to help you learn how questions are asked on this site.  Visit our [tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) for more info.)

Comment: @AlexP & JBH: The story begins after the state government has already broken down and all services disrupted, with the only reasons being a hijacking of the state government and an expulsion of first all corporate investment, and then all law and order. It's a 2500 word piece so I guess I glossed over those details about the arrival to the current position, in favour of focusing on character exploration during the events that transpire during the blackout. I suppose I was looking for a story-based decision that I have to make personally.

Comment: You are correct.  However, backstory is very important.  You can't just gloss over how the breakdown occured because that will in many ways dictate the federal response (or limit the available responses).  @AlexP really is right, as a writer, you need to worry about the journey.  Remember, Tolkien wrote what we, today, call "The Silmarillion" as backstory to the books he really wanted to write: "The Hobbit" and "The Lord of the Rings" series.  He did it because, without the backstory, you can't write a consistent story.

Comment: I would say, the president is going to insult people on Twitter, laugh at them and throw paper towels at them (you know, because they have been flooded). That's how the current president handles crisis. April fool sarcasm over. What do you mean by breakdown?

Comment: "hijacking of the state government and an expulsion of first all corporate investment, and then all law and order" A communist putsch? That would be extremely unlikely and the govt would have stepped in much earlier. That kind of thing would also probably considered a secession, which is not allowed bu the US constitution. I mean, it's too extreme to have that state inside a federal republic.

Comment: Did not think this through at all according to these very well informed comments. Backstory is key to making story believable and allowing readers to connect. Not sure how the state breaks down to the level of basically being the equivalent of the Bermuda Triangle or a blackhole on the continental US. If the government had an interest in allowing it to happen, however? Could be a situation where every “inconvenient situation” would be sent there (prisoners, enemies of the state, etc). Or maybe I’ve been watching too much Prison Break.

Comment: Well, CA is headed in just that direction: just sit back and enjoy the show!!  Realistically, I don't think either neighboring states or a central government (of a 1st world, prosperous country) would let things get quite so bad. Chances are good if this were the US, various contingencies would have already been put in place. If there were any hint or whiff of (e.g.) communist or socialist revolution, you can bet the entire US Armed Forces would be on top of that faster than you can say *Workers of the world...!*

Comment: "*A communist putsch?*" +100

Comment: First World governments don't just break down.  They **slowly** devolve into dystopia.

Comment: What happened to the governor? Was the National Guard called in? Was the federal government informed?

Comment: "no news crews reporting from inside the state, so nobody gets further information" - virtually impossible in modern world, there are just too many channels, from the internet to ham radio. The rest of the nation will immediately get on high alert.

Comment: Sorry, It seems that my quote was form another question and I mixed the comments. Yet I still think that without knowing more on what caused the breakdown, it is not possible to answer the question. My main problem is that it does not make sense that nothing has been done to avoid this breakdown. If the federal govt did not do anything to prevent it, it's almost impossible to predict his future actions. But that depend on the reason of the breakdown. Some are hard to mitigate like hurricanes but they rarely degenerate into a state of total chaos.

Comment: The approach I took was based off a fictional prison called Penitenciaría Federal de Sona from Prison Break. It's a prison where all guards have vacated the interior building due to riots and the prisoners roam free inside. Paraphrasing the top guy "they thought it would descend into anarchy, but we have rules and are a society." Outside the main building, there are guard towers and an electrocuted fence.

Comment: My fictional state was meant to be analogous to the prison, and the "outside world" was the rest of the US. They both have strong incentives to keep each other separate; the government wants a dumping ground, the prisoners want to be left alone.

Comment: "*the government wants a dumping ground, the prisoners want to be left alone.*"  Go watch the 1981 movie "Escape From New York".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The U.S. Government has a whole department (FEMA) that is set up to deal with these sorts of issues.  If the State Declares a State of Emergency, FEMA can go in and provide additional resources to address the concern of the state(s).  Additionally, the President may declare an National Emergency and the provisions that are needed to remedy the National Emergency issue.  These can include such things as suspension of Posse Comitatus and allow for the use of the military in law enforcement measures, as well as nationalizing the National Guard units for the State in question.

This National Emergency will exist until of one of three things happens:  The President declares the crisis over, The President does not renew the Emergency after one year of it being enacted, or Congress revokes the declaration in a joint resolution.

Answer (score 5):

You are positing an unusual event.  Historically, states crumble from the top down.  The process is called 'balkanization' after the region in Europe that is currently Romania, Bulgaria, Albenia... that used to be part of the Ottoman Empire.  The most recent fragmentation there is what used to be Yugoslavia.

The second way your situation is odd:  Why would it happen to ONE state, and not many?  E.g. If something happens in Mississippi, I would expect similar events in Arkansas, Alabama.

Why would it occur by state boundary?  Few states are homogenous.

How would it break down in such a way that no news got out?  No news is news.  I would expect news agencies to be flying drones and slow planes over to find out what was going on.  If the state is organized enough to stop this, then why isn't it using that ability to impose civil order?

Please re-edit your question and give us some history.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest watching the first few episodes of *Designated Survivor*. It runs through a fictional (obviously!) attack on the US capitol during the SOTU, and all three branches of government (congress, supreme court, executive branch) are destroyed barring about four people.

Because it is a terrorist attack, and huge, and the government is now gone, there is pandemonium. There is an outcry against Muslims.

It's against this backdrop that Michigan rebels against the newly sworn - in president.

It's impossible to know how closely this would or wouldn't match your scenario, but the show did a great job outlining the available responses to the POTUS and the relative powers of state governors; state law enforcement vs Federal law enforcement, etc.

In this story, the new POTUS was determined to keep Michigan in the union. He saw that if he didn't it could create a domino effect. He made some unethical choices towards preserving the union of fifty states.

Again, watch the first few episodes of that - i bet it'll be useful for you.